# Spin $1/2$ motivation for twistor theory in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, spinors, twistor

I was watching this Youtube [video](https://youtu.be/uMn0jUeYf30?t=1538) (I have linked it at the relevant timestamp) and to paraphrase Dr. Woit' s motivation for twistor theory:

> Within the standard way of thinking about general relativity framework
> it is difficult and alien to describe the spin $1/2$ particle. You
> can't do it at all. You have develop a mathematically more
> sophisticated way of thinking of general relativity and it's very
> artificial.

### Question

Can someone flesh out the mathematical details of this argument (more specifically how twistor solves it and why the standard way is artificial)?

Comment: I don’t understand what is “artificial” about vierbeins, which I believe are the standard way. It seems fairly natural to me to have an orthonormal frame at each point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most standard GR textbooks approach the problem of curved space-time using the notion of tensor fields. Spin 1/2 particles, on the other hand, are defined using spinors which are semi-tensor like quantities. Although one can define these particles using the Dirac equation, it works in flat space-time... and there doesn't seem to be an intuitive and natural way to extend this equation to a general curved space-time. The issue here is that we are trying to define the transformation of spinor like quantities using tensor fields, which is quite artificial (at least how I interpreted Dr Woit's statement).

So a better way is to start with 2-component spinor fields. To ensure that a manifold M admits spin bundle, it should satisfy two conditions:
(1) M must be space-time orientable
(2)The topological invariant - second Stieffel-Whitney class must vanish

These Spinors are complex quantities and it can be shown that the real tensor fields are a special subclass of these spinorial quantities. So all of the standard tensor transformation that we use in GR can be derived from a general class of spinor transformation.
In other words, given that M admits spin bundle, these 2 component spinor fields can be interpreted as more fundamental than tensor quantities. It follows that you can describe any arbitrary spinor field ( spin n/2) in a general curved space-time using a 2-component spinor treatment. (Point to note: this description is very particular to (3+1) dim space-time)
Read: " Spinors and Spacetime " Volume I - R. Penrose, W. Rindler.

Twistors are defined using 2-components spinor fields only. A Twistor is essentially a pair of spinors that describes the momentum and angular momentum of a massless particle. In Twistor theory, you can describe massless spinor fields in a flat space-time using Twistor functions (via what is known as Penrose transform)...and this is a 1-1 correspondence. The motivation for Twistor theory is to give an alternate geometrization of conventional physics where your space-time plays a secondary role...and various fields and curvatures are essentially an emergent property. Either way, these 2-component spinor fields play a key role in all of this description. ( Suggested reading: "Twistor theory- An approach to quantisation of fields and space-time" by R. Penrose, MacCallum (1972)
)